# React-quil nextjs use problem ref not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-quill

When I connect NEXTJS react-quill, quill does not work.

[screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJLon.png)

I have attached a quill to my site. When I connected Quill the codes were class component. then I switched to arrow function. There was an error while processing
create.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import axios from "axios";
import Main from "../../layouts/main";
const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import("react-quill"), { ssr: false });
import cookie from "react-cookies";
import { withRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    editorHtml: "",
    title: "",
    image: {},
    message: "",
    error_message: "",
    error_type: "",
    category_id: 1,
    token: cookie.load("userToken"),
  });
  const handleChange = (html) => {
    setState({ editorHtml: html });
  };
  const selectImage = (image) => {
    console.log(image);
  };

  const onSubmitForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const image = document.querySelector("#image").files[0];

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", image);
    formData.append("title", this.state.title);
    formData.append("text", this.state.editorHtml);
    formData.append("category_id", this.state.category_id);
    if (this.state.title.length <= 255) {
      axios
        .post("http://exapmle.com/api/post/store", formData, {
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            Authorization: "Bearer" + this.state.token,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data.success == true) {
            this.setState({ message: "Blog created!" });
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.setState({ message: "" });
              this.props.router.push("/");
            }, 5000);
          }
        });
    }
    if (this.state.title.length >= 256) {
      this.setState({
        error_type: "title",
        error_message: "Blog name error!",
      });
    }
  };

  const apiPostNewsImage = (data) => {
    axios
      .post("http://exapmle.com/api/image-upload", data, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => console.log(res));
  };

  const imageHandler = () => {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "file");
    input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
    input.click();

    input.onchange = async () => {
      const file = input.files[0];
      const formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("image", file);

      // Save current cursor state
      const range = quill.getSelection(true);

      // Insert temporary loading placeholder image
      //   this.quill.insertEmbed(range.index, "ssurat");

      // Move cursor to right side of image (easier to continue typing)
      quill.setSelection(range.index + 1);
      const res = await axios.post(
        "http://exapmle.com/api/image-upload",
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      ); // API post, returns image location as string e.g. 'http://www.example.com/images/foo.png'

      // Remove placeholder image
      quill.deleteText(range.index, 1);

      // Insert uploaded image
      //   this.quill.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', res.body.image);
      quill.insertEmbed(range.index, "image", res.data);
    };
  };

  return (
    <Main title="Create blog">
      <section className="col-12 col-lg-9 shadow bg-white p-3">
        {state.token && (
          <form
            className="row my-4 col-11 col-lg-8 mx-auto"
            onSubmit={(event) => onSubmitForm(event)}
          >
            <h5 className="title col-12 my-3"> Create blog </h5>
            {state.message && (
              <div className="alert alert-success">{state.message}</div>
            )}
            <div className="col-12">
              <small className="text-danger p-1"></small>
              <div className="input-group p-1">
                <div className="custom-file">
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    name="image"
                    id="image"
                    className="custom-file-input"
                    onChange={(event) =>
                      setState({
                        ...state,
                        image: event.target.files[0],
                      })
                    }
                    id="image"
                    required
                  />
                  <label
                    className="custom-file-label"
                    data-browse="Select"
                    htmlFor="image"
                    aria-describedby="image"
                  >
                    Image blog
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col-12 col-lg-6">
              <small className="text-danger p-1 col-12"></small>
              <div className="form-label-group p-1">
                <input
                  name="title"
                  type="text"
                  id="title"
                  onChange={(event) =>
                    setState({
                      ...state,
                      title: event.target.value,
                    })
                  }
                  className={
                    state.error_type == "title"
                      ? "form-control border border-danger"
                      : "form-control"
                  }
                  // border border-danger
                  placeholder="Category name"
                  autoFocus={true}
                  required
                />
                <label htmlFor="title"> Blog name </label>
                {state.error_type == "title" && state.error_message && (
                  <div className="text-danger">{state.error_message}</div>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col-12 col-lg-6 mt-3">
              <div className="form-label-group p-1">
                <select name="category_id" className="form-control">
                  <option value="1"> Category</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col-12">
              <ReactQuill
                 ref={(el) => {
                   quill = el;
                 }}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                modules={{
                  toolbar: {
                    container: [
                      [
                        { header: "1" },
                        { header: "2" },
                        { header: [3, 4, 5, 6] },
                        { font: [] },
                      ],
                      [{ size: [] }],
                      ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
                      [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
                      ["link", "image", "video"],
                      ["clean"],
                      ["code-block"],
                    ],
                    handlers: {
                      image: imageHandler,
                    },
                  },
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <button className="btn btn-success mx-auto mt-5">
              Create blog
            </button>
          </form>
        )}
        {!state.token && (
          <div className="alert alert-warning d-flex align-items-center d-flex flex-wrap">
            this alert
          </div>
        )}
      </section>
    </Main>
  );
};

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

this not work

```
 ref={(el) => {
  quill = el;
 }}
```

When I connect NEXTJS react-quill, quill does not work.

Comment: You probably need to make sure the ref is defined at the moment you're trying to call it, could you share context where you do "quill.getSelection"? More on refs in React: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#cautions

Comment: @vitkarpov not work

Comment: You'll need to provide more code around where the error happens. Where does `quill.getSelection` get called exactly?

Comment: @juliomalves, code

Comment: @Kickster did you get answer?